# JAVA: Replacing a character in JTextArea, given a specific row and col

Tags: java

I am writing a program which interprets a Befunge(93) program.
As you know, Befunge has special command, 'p'.
This command puts some given (by the program itself) character into the 'codespace' itself, for which I am curious about this very problem.
I have made all the other things done well, including the execution of the command 'p'.
**But I couldn't make the codespace (which I implemented with a JTextArea) dynamically interact with 'p' code.**

I mean, when the Befunge program begins to run, I save the JTextArea into a 80*25 char array, and all the operations are done in the array.
The 'p' command, also is operated only internally, merely replacing a character on the array. (and not the source JTextArea)

I want to visualize the change of the codespace, so I am asking:

**How do you replace a character at, say (2, 3), in a JTextArea, with another character?**

Answer (score 3):

According to [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) it might be done by

```
int lineNumber = 2;
int charAtLineOffset = 3;

int offset = area.getLineStartOffset(lineNumber) + charAtLineOffset;
area.replaceRange(new String(newChar), offset , offset + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this maybe?

```
void replaceChar(int row, int col, char replaceChar)
{
    int lineOffset = jTextArea.getLineStartOffset(row);
    jTextArea.replaceRange(new String(replaceCHar), lineOffset + col, lineOffset + col + 1);
}
```